# How to configure routes in Angular properly

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-routerlink

I'm learning Routes in Angular. I'm following some tutorials from Pluralsight. Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6xlhe1) for the same. I tried a very basic code to understand routing. But I'm getting this error:

> "Unexpected value 'PostList' declared by the module 'PostModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation."

I debugged the code, and here's the culprit:

**post-list.component.ts**

```
import { PostService } from './post.service';

export class PostList {

  constrcutor(private postservice: PostService) {
    postservice.getAllPosts();
  }
}
```

I'm trying to read posts which are already stored somewhere (I'm using JSONPlaceholder). I want to show all the posts on one page and then on click event I want to navigate into the details of that particular post. Here is my:

**post.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostService {
  constructor() {}

  getAllPosts() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json))
  }
}
```

and here's my:
**post.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PostDetails } from './post-details.component';
import { PostList } from './post-list.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  imports:[
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {path: 'posts', component: PostList},
      {path: 'posts/:id', component: PostDetails}
    ])
  ],
  declarations:[PostList, PostDetails]
})
export class PostModule {}
```

My problem is Routing. I'm not able to set routes correctly. I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6xlhe1) for the same. Please point out my mistakes. I really want to learn Angular with all best practices. Please correct me.

Comment: For the PostList Component, There is no Component decorator to define that it is a component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to add `@Component` to your class

```
import { PostService } from './post.service';

// added this below ↓
@Component({
  selector: 'whatever',
  templateUrl: './my-template.template.html',
})
export class PostList {

  constrcutor(private postservice: PostService) {
    postservice.getAllPosts();
  }
}
```

The problem is that since your class is not being passed that component decorator, adding it to `declarations` seems like you added the wrong thing to angular, since it only expects components in there (which have @component)

**edit:** checked your stackblitz and fixed the issue but then you get an error with the PostDetails declaration, for the same reasons. Please find the Component's options and learn how to use it properly, you need to add the @Component decorator to all instances, and you have to add a selector and template to it (selector is how is it going to be targeted from the html, and template is what the component html is), you can have templateUrl to target another file with the html, you can add styles or styleUrls, etc....

hope this helps, feel free to ask anything further

Comment: Actually I could have used `ng g c productList` but I decided to write the code from scratch so that I'll learn what I am writing and Why I am writing. I'll be more careful next time.

Comment: hey, I'm a writer myself... I write all my components, directives and services like that. And I assure you this is the best way to learn (and to avoid unnecessary code that gets autocreated).

Keep doing it :and you'll see these kinds of issues before they happen in no time. I support your way of writing it all!

Comment: Sir one last question. In my **post.service.ts** you can see I've created a method **getAllPosts()** which will fetch posts from the server. So which is the best place to call this method, inside the constructor or inside ngOnInt ?

Comment: I'm asking this because later I'll be implementing pre-fetch data code, so that user will not get an empty page.I'll use some loading icons till the data is loaded from the server.

Comment: for consistency onInit makes more sense, since this gets triggered AFTER the component has been built (constructor triggers it after the component has been built but before returning the component object to the app if this makes sense).....

So, it might virtually make no difference in your particular case, but it is good to know that they happen at different times... construction > binding (onChanges) > onInit > afterViewInit... etc, these lifecycle hooks are googleable in case you forget :) I forget all the time